# Where Clause in eloquent is responding with `No Properties`

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am new to laravel. I am trying to keep a where clause for the get method like this.

```
$employees = newdb::where('status', 'Active');
$response = $employees;
return response()->json($response,200);
```

But i am getting No Properties as output

In PHP I used this

```
"SELECT * FROM newdb WHERE status = 'Draft'";
```

What am i doing wrong? I tried different suggestions But none worked correctly. How do i do this? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: If you use where you have to use `->get()` as well

Comment: I have one more question how do we add `Order by` and `multiple where` conditions to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where` method returns `Builder` object. So, you have to call `get` method on it to fetch data.

Try this

```
$employees = newdb::where('status', 'Active')->get();

return response()->json($employees, 200);
```

Comment: I have one more question how do we add `Order by` to this?

Comment: @Prakash Use `orderBy` method like this `$employees = 
 newdb::where('status', 'Active')->orderBy('status', 'desc')->get();`